# R table() function; how do I get column names included?

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe with df$Cat, df$IsYellow. Both columns can either be "Yes" or "No"

How do I generate the 2x2 table and also have Cat and IsYellow printed on the table so that I know which side of the table belongs to Cat and which side belongs to IsYellow?

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(Cat=sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size=10, replace=TRUE),
                 IsYellow=sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size=10, replace=TRUE))
table(df)
##      IsYellow
## Cat   No Yes
##   No   3   1
##   Yes  2   4
```

Comment: It should be noted this works because `df` has names - you can specify whatever name you want to a table if you want it to display - `table(ILikeCats=df$Cat,TheSunisYellow=df$IsYellow)`

Comment: This is basically showing that the the poster didn't even try to call `table`.

Comment: But that's what we're here for, isn't it?