# Add variable names to tables of two vectors in R

Tags: r

this is weird. Overe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015425/r-table-function-how-do-i-get-column-names-included) someone asks the basic question of how to do a 2x2 table in R.

The answer is good in a way, but it tables the entire dataframe.
In larger data frames this won't work, you need to specify the two vectors to crosstab.

The problem here is that when you table the data frame, as below, you get nice headers indicating which variable is in the rows and which is in the columns. *This is absent in the more frequent use case where you table two vectors*.

```
df <- data.frame(Cat=sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size=10, replace=TRUE),
                 IsYellow=sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size=10, replace=TRUE))
#Compare this
table(df)
#With this
table(df$Cat, df$IsYellow)
```

how do I get variable names in the second option?

Comment: Do you mean `table(Cat = df$Cat, IsYellow = df$IsYellow)`?

Comment: also `do.call(table, df)`

Comment: In the second call to `table(.)`, you are passing _unnamed_ vectors, whereas in the first they are named (column names in the frame). Adding to @jpsmith's comment, see `table(quux = df$Cat, stuff = df$IsYellow)` to see that any name will do.

Comment: `table(df[,c("Cat", "IsYellow")])` also works if you dont want to manually enter in the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to wrap in `with()`:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  Cat = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  IsYellow = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)

with(df, table(Cat, IsYellow))
#>      IsYellow
#> Cat   No Yes
#>   No   1   3
#>   Yes  4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the `dnn`-argument:

```r
df = data.frame(Cat = sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size = 10L, replace = TRUE),
                IsYellow = sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size = 10L, replace = TRUE))

table(df$Cat, df$IsYellow, dnn = colnames(df))
#>      IsYellow
#> Cat   No Yes
#>   No   5   2
#>   Yes  1   2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>